# Attribute "inherit" must be declared for element type "put-list-attribute"

Tags: java, spring, apache, tiles

I'm using Apache tile 3.0.5 with Spring MVC. But, when I'm trying to include some page specific JS/CSS using "put-attribute" then I'm getting error message:

**Attribute "inherit" must be declared for element type "put-list-attribute".**

Below is my tile.xml file:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC
       "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 2.0//EN"
       "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_2_0.dtd">

<tiles-definitions>

    <!-- Default Main Template -->
    <definition name="mainTemplate" template="/WEB-INF/tiles/template.jsp">
        <put-attribute name="title" value="Simple Tiles 2 Example" type="string" />
        <put-attribute name="header" value="/WEB-INF/tiles/header.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="navigation" value="/WEB-INF/tiles/nav.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/tiles/blank.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="footer" value="/WEB-INF/tiles/footer.jsp" />
        <put-list-attribute name="javascripts">
         <add-attribute value="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js" />
         <add-attribute value="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" />
         <add-attribute value="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js" />
     </put-list-attribute>
     <put-list-attribute name="stylesheets">
         <add-attribute value="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
         <add-attribute value="/resources/css/business-casual.css" />
         <add-attribute value="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css" />
     </put-list-attribute>
    </definition>
 
  <!-- Default Main Template -->
    <definition name="dataEntryTemplate" template="/WEB-INF/tiles/data-entry-template.jsp">
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/tiles/blank.jsp" />
    </definition>
 
    <definition name="home" extends="mainTemplate">
     <put-attribute name="title" value="Home" type="string" />
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/views/index.jsp" />
    </definition>

    <definition name="manage-student" extends="mainTemplate">
     <put-attribute name="title" value="Manage Student" type="string" />
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/views/manage-student.jsp" />
        <put-list-attribute name="javascripts" cascade="true" inherit="true">
         <add-attribute value="/static/stylesheets/sign-in.js" />
     </put-list-attribute>
    </definition>
</tiles-definitions>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you add element inherit="true"  for your first put-list-attribute tag

ie

```
<put-list-attribute name="javascripts" inherit="true">
```

Hope this solves your issue.

Comment: I have already added that. You can see in my above settings file.

Comment: Just a hit, but in the mainTemplate defination you have 2 put-list-attribute tags right now. might be some of the js or stylesheet is trying to inherit from a default library and requesting you to add inherit=true. can you try it once

Comment: I have added inherit=true in the extended template definition and which it throwing compilation error . Also, inside main template definition if I'm trying to add  inherit="true"( <put-list-attribute name="javascripts" inherit="true"> ) getting same error.

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same problem

it's because of the DTD, which in our case was for tiles 2 (copied from some tutorial) but we have Tiles 3 installed.

Replace the DTD with this instead:

```
<!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 3.0//EN" "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_3_0.dtd">
```